# Laravel 5.6 - vuejs code splitting with laravel-mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, vuejs2

I am trying to split out the code from my `vue` files into some smaller file that only been used in specific route.

for example, i have a `mobile.vue` component that only show up when user use mobile device.

initially, if I don't split the code this is how I get `vue component` into `app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');///typical for laravel to have a bootstrap.js for other pages.

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('v-mobile', require('./components/MobileComponent.vue'));
```

following [this link](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/code-splitting-with-laravel-mix), below are my `app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('v-mobile', (resolve) => {
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "/js/v-mobile" */'./components/MobileComponent.vue')
    .then((MobileComponent) => {
      resolve(MobileComponent.default);
    });
});
```

and I did separate out the other packages with `webpack.mix.js`:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.extract(['jquery', 'vue', 'axios'])
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

as I `nom run watch`, I can see my `v-mobile` been spitted out:

[image]

But when I run the page, I got an error from `vendor.js`:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '__esModule' of
>   undefined

I am fairly new with `webpack`. What seems to be the issue here? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

I found out the solution.

As it turn out, we don't need to mess with `webpack`. First of all, you will need to install `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`.

Then just in the `app.js`, change this line:

```
Vue.component('vmobile', require('./components/MobileComponent.vue'));
```

to:

```
const vmobile = ()=> import(/* webpackChunkName: "./js/vmobile" */'./components/MobileComponent.vue')
```

Comment: I've tried to do the same as you, but I'm getting a `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element` error. Did you use the custom elements as you always have?

Comment: @AlexGodbehere Same here. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I don't get the error, I install babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import and declare my component in app.js like so `Vue.component('add-student-form', () => import('./components/AddStudentForm'))` work like a charm thanks.